# How to compare a column with the columns in the same dataframe in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a date column "a" which needs to be compared to another two columns "b" and "c" of type date. All these columns belong to same data frame.

The sample data looks like this

```
{
    "a": "10 - 12 - 2019",
    "somecol": {
        "startdate": "10 - 06 - 2019",
        "enddate": "10 - 12 - 2020"
    }
}
```

if col("a") is in between "startdate" and "enddate" it is a valid record for me. How can i do this in spark. One thing is i can explode the "somecol" and then do a join and compare with condition. But, I would like to know if there are any other ways.

Expected Output:

since the column "a"s value is in between "startdate" and "enddate" the final output is

```
{
    "a": "10 - 12 - 2019",
    "somecol": {
        "startdate": "10 - 06 - 2019",
        "enddate": "10 - 12 - 2020"
    },
    "status": "valid"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output ? that will help

Comment: @BalajiReddy updated my question

Comment: can i assume all  3 columns are in single row ?  like a,startdate,enddate ?

Comment: @BalajiReddy yes you can assume that all 3 are in same row

Comment: okay. understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val inputDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
        ("2018-12-12", "2018-12-01", "2018-12-31"),
        ("2019-02-12", "2018-12-11", "2018-12-12")
    )).toDF("ds", "start", "end")
      .select(col("ds").cast("date"), col("start").cast("date"), col("end").cast("date"))

val outputDF = inputDF.withColumn("status", col("ds") >= col("start") &&  col("ds") <= col("end"))
outputDF.show()


+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|        ds|     start|       end| status|
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|2018-12-12|2018-12-01|2018-12-31|   true|
|2019-02-12|2018-12-11|2018-12-12|  false|
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
   val data = Seq(("10-12-2019", "10-06-2019", "10-12-2020"),
      ("11-12-2020", "10-06-2019", "10-12-2020"))

    val spark = getSession()

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("a", "startdate", "enddate")


    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date

    val modifiedDF = df.withColumn("a", to_date($"a", "dd-MM-yyyy"))
      .withColumn("startdate", to_date($"startdate", "dd-MM-yyyy"))
.withColumn("enddate", to_date($"enddate", "dd-MM-yyyy"))

  modifiedDF.withColumn("isValid", !$"a".gt($"enddate").and(!$"a".lt($"enddate"))).show()
```

**Result**

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|         a| startdate|   enddate|isValid|
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|2019-12-10|2019-06-10|2020-12-10|   true|
|2020-12-11|2019-06-10|2020-12-10|  false|
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```